# How to specify the current kernel's header in the debian/control file?

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg, packaging

I am trying to modify [this](https://github.com/alexeikh/droidcam-deb) debian source package which requires the the user to manually install the current Linux kernel's header (with `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` before installing droidcam.

However, can this be automated using the `debian/control` file or the `postinst` script, so that the user does not have to manually install it?

Comment: Seems like you need DKMS

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is not a complete solution. It does not cover if the user want keep an older kernel.

Instead of headers only

```
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, build-essential, linux-headers-generic | linux-headers-generic-pae | linux-headers-lowlatency | linux-headers-lowlatency-pae
```

Put kernel & headers as requirement

```
Depends: ${misc:Depends}, build-essential, linux-generic | linux-generic-pae | linux-lowlatency | linux-lowlatency-pae
```

So this way:

- If the kernel is last version, it will install its headers.
- If the kernel is old version, it will install both the last version kernel with its headers.